# Split Dataframe column with Regex and fill in NA values for not found captured groups

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a column with values like this

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""Text
Electric consumption L1 (kiosk) (01/02-15/02/2022)
AC Expense L2-13b (21/12-12/01/2023)
AC Overtime Expense L4-24,25,26
Overtime Expense (16/05-15/06/2021)"""), sep=";")
```

I want to extract the above into 3 columns: Expense, Unit and Time columns.
The desired output should look like this.

| Expense | Unit | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Electric consumption | L1 (kiosk) | (01/02-15/02/2022) |
| AC Expense | L2-13b | (21/12-12/01/2023) |
| AC Overtime Expense | L4-24,25,26 | np.nan |
| Overtime Expense | np.nan | (16/05-15/06/2021) |

However, this syntax `df['Text'].str.extract('(?P<Expense>.*) (?P<Unit>[L|B].*)(?P<Time>\(.*)', expand=True)`  only works for the first two 2 examples in the above table, and results in `np.nan` for all columns regarding the last 2 examples. What should I do to get the desired output like so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working version:

```
df['Text'].str.extract(r'^(?P<Expense>.*?(?= [L|B]| \()) ?(?:(?P<Unit>[L|B].*?(?= \(\d+|$))|(?=\()) ?(?:(?P<Date>\(\d{2}/\d{2}-\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\))|(?=$))', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The text pattern is complex, so `TIME` are extracted with different matching.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
data = {'Text': [
    'Electric consumption L1 (kiosk) (01/02-15/02/2022)',
    'AC Expense L2-13b (21/12-12/01/2023)',
    'AC Overtime Expense L4-24,25,26',
    'Overtime Expense (16/05-15/06/2021)'
]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pattern = r'^([a-z ]*?)(?:(\s[L|B]\d.*?(?:\s*\([a-z]+\)\s)*)(\s\([\d\-/]+\))*|\s(\([\d\-/]+\)))$'
df[['Expense', 'Unit', 'Time', 'Time2']] = 
        df['Text'].str.extract(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df = df.replace('', np.nan, regex=True)
mask = df['Time'].isnull()
df.loc[mask, 'Time'] = df.loc[mask, 'Time2']
df.drop('Time2', axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == object else x)
print(df)
print(df[['Expense', 'Unit', 'Time']])
```

**Output**

|  | Expense | Unit | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Electric consumption | L1 (kiosk) | (01/02-15/02/2022) |
| 1 | AC Expense | L2-13b | (21/12-12/01/2023) |
| 2 | AC Overtime Expense | L4-24,25,26 | NaN |
| 3 | Overtime Expense | NaN | (16/05-15/06/2021) |